# Use the regular expression feature of Oracle to find all movies whose titles include three or more words

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

What code should I use to only show titles with three or more words.

So far I have used

```
SELECT  title
FROM movie
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (title, '\s+( )')
```

or would this code work? So far it has but is there another way?

```
SELECT  title
FROM movie
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (title, '(\s[A-Z]*){2}')
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by a word, use

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (title, '\S+(\s+\S+){2}')
```

Or,

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (title, '\w+(\W+\w+){2}')
```

Or,

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (title, '[[:alpha:]]+(\s+[[:alpha:]]+){2}')
```

Where:

- `\S+`  - word is non-whitespaces
- `\w+` - word contains letters, digits and underscores
- `\s+` - whitespaces
- `[[:alpha:]]+` -  word contains letters
- `{2}` - two repetitions.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use regex! Instead return movies whose name has at least 2 spaces:

```
SELECT  title
FROM movie
WHERE title LIKE '% % %'
```

Comment: I doubt a `! ? .` is a string containing three words, so I added some more options to my answer.

Comment: @RyszardCzech I strongly doubt any such edge case exists. Can you find even one such case?

Comment: Yes, I can and do find a lot of such cases. You can't imagine what mess people keep in their databases.

Comment: within the domain of movie titles? Can you name one?

Comment: @RyszardCzech you took my question too literally. I meant “Can you find even one such case *of any commercially released movie, and if so tell us here in a comment*".

Comment: Guys, I meant what I said. Our customers literally keep any junk among what they think should be some specific content. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: The OP doesn't define "word".  I think that interpreted a symbol such as `'?'` separated by spaces as a valid word is a *very* reasonable interpretation of the question.  After all, a solution using regular expressions wouldn't be checking strings against a dictionary of allowed words, so it also has its assumptions and limitations.

Comment: I suppose if the title had been wrongly entered with additional spaces, such as `'Star  Wars'` or `'Mad Max '` then a regex could avoid counting it. But if there are serious data quality issues then you won't get a reliable result whatever approach you use. Like @Bohemian I doubt there are any movie titles containing a punctuation character as a separate word, though, so I wouldn't personally worry about `! ? .`

Comment: Actually now I think about it, I've seen `! ? .` and it's rubbish.